# Recursive toString Method

Tags: java, recursion

I'm working on my current assignment which is to create a LinkedList data structure, and I've created it as well as the other methods, and it works perfectly fine. I'm on my last question which is to make a toString method. Which is supposed to:

"toString method to return a String representation of the list. Separate each item with a comma, and enclose the items in braces, e.g. {1,4,7,5}. The public toString method must call a private, recursive method to generate the comma separated list of items. (You may add the braces in the public method though.)"

I have my public toString method working;

```
    public String toString() {
    int size = getSize();
    String str = "{ ";
    Link current = first;

    for(int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++, current = current.next) {
        str += current.getiData() + " ";
    }

    str += " }";
    return str;
}
```

(I know I should be using StringBuilder, just using += temporarily.) However for the private method I'm confused as to even write it. Right now the only way I can think of doing this would be as:

```
private String toString(int x) {
    if(i > 0) {
        toString(--x);
    }
    return ", ";
}
```

Which is just stupid (and really isn't recursion), can anyone clarify what is meant to be done, and/or give pseudo code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the other answers are appropriate from a code standpoint, but I just wanted to add some more theory to help you understand how to get there.  When doing recursion,  you always need two things:  a base case and a recursive case.  The base case is something incredibly simple to solve and the recursive case is how you work down toward the solvable simple case.

A Linked List is kind of a recursive data structure itself.  For example, if you have a Linked List of 10 items, you can picture as a single node with a Linked List of 9 items attached to it.

So for the base case (again, borrowing from @Chris' answer), the simplest possible list to do a `toString()` on is an empty list.  So your base case will look something this (pseudocode):

```
if(list is empty)
{
   return "";
}
```

Your recursive case, then, needs to take your existing Linked List and try to work downward toward your base case.  The easiest way to do that is to break off a small piece of the problem that you know you can solve, solve it and then work on the slightly smaller problem you have left.  In the case of printing a Linked List, that means that you can just grab one item from the list, translate it to a string, and then worry about the rest of the list.  So your recursive case will looking something like this (pseudocode):

```
if(list is not empty)
{
   String x = take the current node and translate it to a string;

   Add x to your running value of the String value of the entire list

   Recursively call this function with the next node in the list
   (you reduce your list size by 1 with each call and work down to your base case of an empty list)
}
```

Hopefully that helps you understand how to reach a solution recursively for this problem.  There are certainly plenty of variations on how to make it work; there's not one "right" way to do it recursively just like there's not one "right" way to write a loop, but the general "base case" and "recursive case" model of thinking is usually the best place to start.

Answer (score 5):

You want something like this (gives the basic idea of recursion, will not work)

```
privat String toString(Link link) {
  if (link.isLast()) {
    return link.value();
  }
  else {
    return link.value() + toString(link.next());
  }
}
```

Comment: You may want to tweak that base case.  This will NPE on an empty list.

Comment: There are a lot of things that won't work with my code. It was meant as a pointer on how recursion works, not a working solution. I preferred this way since this obviously is homework and because recursion specifically was the problem OP had.

Answer (score 1):

It is somewhat bizarre, because the `toString` method's signature has no parameters, which means the need for another method. In a linked list, each node has `data` and a `pointer` to the next node.

```
public String getData(Node n, String value)
{
     if(n == null)
     {
         // We know we're at the end, so don't proceed.
         return value;
     }
     else
     {
         // n isn't empty, and ignoring the lack of stringbuilder
         value += n.getData();
         // Make a recursive call with the next value in the list, and the new string.
         return getData(n.next(), value);
     }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could also do `return "";` and `return n.value + getData(n.next());` to  avoid passing the `String` along the entire recursive call chain.